# Add <object> to DOM with AJAX

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

So if I hard code the `object` into my cshtml document it works -

```
<div class="col-md-6 imagePreviewer" style="height:200px;">
    <object data="~/Content/Images/casedocs/2335421_passport.JPG"></object>
</div>
```

but I need to load the image dynamically (on click) -

```
$('.linkDoc').on('click', function () {
        var div = $('.imagePreviewer');
        if (div.length > 0) {
            $(div).children("object").remove();
            var obj = document.createElement("object");
            $(obj).attr("data", "~/Content/Images/casedocs/2335421_passport.JPG")
                    .css("height", "200px")
                    .css("width", "200px");

            $(div).append(obj);
        }
    });
```

why is it not working when I try to load the `object` dynamically?

Comment: why do you remove the object instead of just setting the element's data attribute to an empty string and then to the value that you're looking for?

Comment: Let me ask the dumb question here: why are you using the object tag to load an image?

Comment: @ChrisPratt It's not just for an image. I could be trying to preview a pdf, doc, etc..

Answer (score 0):

Just leave an object element with empty data attribute and load that attribute dynamically.